# Can't find iframe in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, vimeo

I'm trying to find the `iframe` tag in order to open a popup window. If I use the `<video>` tag it works fine but when I use iframe tag it does not. What is the problem?

```html
<div class="about__img-overlay">
  <div class="video3">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/807322046?h=0d933f4470&autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&controls=0&muted=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" class="about__img-one"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.video-container iframe').forEach(vid => {
  vid.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelector('.popup-video').style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

Comment: As it's a cross-domain iframe you cannot interact with it. This is a security limitation

Comment: Click events in documents loaded in iframes bubble up to the top of those documents then stop. They don't continue bubbling through the iframe into the parent document.